# Knockoutjs working with multiple view models

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to get Knockout js working with jQueryMobile and am hitting a few problems when moving between pages.

I would like to try and keep the page transitions in JQM and therefore I would like to use either the multiple page option (multiple pages defined in one html file) or load the additional pages into the DOM as detailed in default AJAX behaviour section of the documentation.

[JQM Page Transition Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

I have two individual Knockoutjs pages working both with a separate view model on each.  Both pages work perfectly until I attempt to link them together through JQM.

Whichever page I attempt to load I get an error relating to a mapping on the other page. I can only assume that both pages are loaded into the single DOM and when Knockout applies the bindings it is looking for properties that do not exist.

I have attempted to make a jsFiddle to demonstrate this.

[JQM - Knockout Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npJZM/9/)

I am new to both JQM and Knockout so any help appreciated.  If I am taking completely the wrong approach then I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Would I be better attempting to use one ViewModel for the whole site?  If not how can I use Knockoutjs with JQM?

Comment: hmmm Jasper, Google search brought me here.

Comment: I thought lmgtfy is not a way to answer questions in SO, Jasper?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One "master" view model for the whole site would be acceptable. Then, you could do something like this:

```
var masterViewModel = {
   viewModelOne: ...,
   viewModelTwo: ...
}
```

Alternately, you can call the .applyBindings overload to apply bindings to individual elements, rather than the whole DOM:

```
ko.applyBindings(new modelOne("Test", "One"), $("#one")[0]);
ko.applyBindings(new modelTwo("Test", "Two"), $("#two")[0]);
```

Personally, I'd recommend the second approach.

Comment: Great stuff. Does this have any performance implications as I appear to be creating and binding a view model that is completely unnecessary?

Comment: Sure, there's likely a performance overhead in that you don't need to apply bindings on the second page until you show that page. To offset that, you could try invoking .applyBindings for the 2nd div only when the 2nd "page" loads.

Comment: It's a great solution the only trouble is to send from one page to the other some data

Comment: To send data from one page to another, you should share data via passing the data to the second view model. Or, if both pages are on screen at once, use a Pub/Sub library to send a message to the second page.

Comment: Ahaha, been looking for this! Does anyone know where the actual documentation for applyBindings is? Can't seem to find it anywhere on their docs site.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer See this page, scroll down to "Activating Knockout": http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 and Knockout 2.2.1 and tried many approaches before finding a (hopefully) permanent solution to this problem. The hard part is figuring out **when** to apply bindings. When I used jQuery's ready function, that didn't work. I found in the [jQM documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html) to bind upon the pageinit event callback instead of the document ready function. However, this callback is fired off **every time** a page is rendered for the first time so if you have 5 jQM pages, it could be fired off 5 times and you're only supposed to apply KO bindings once.

The solution I eventually used was the following:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (e) {
    var pageId = e.target.id;

    for (var i in VIEW_MODELS) {
        var vm = VIEW_MODELS[i];
        if (pageId == vm.View) {
            ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById(vm.View));
        }
    }
});
```

What this is doing is every time a jQM page is initially rendered, it searches through my view models to find the view model associated with the upcoming view and applies bindings. Since pages are only initialized the first time they are rendered, it will apply ko bindings upon that first rendering and never again.

So far this is working for me but I'd be curious to hear other people's opinions or solutions to using jQM multi-page templates with Knockout.