# Bind a Model Object with multiple pages in jQuery Mobile with Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have knockout js Model, I want to bind that to two pages in jQuery mobile, the first page only contains read only attributes of the model and other page contains elements with which the user can update fields.

```
function ModelViewObject(){
    this.id = "1001";
    this.firstName = ko.observable("First Name"); 
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Last Name");
}

//This page only contains read only values
<div data-role="page" id="pageOne">
    <h1>Id : <span data-bind="text: id()</h1>
</div>

//This page can edit
<div data-role="page" id="pageTwo">
   <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
</div>
```

I could bind it first page or second page at a time.I want to bind the model with two pages, I would really appreciate if some one can help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockoutjs working with multiple view models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795730/knockoutjs-working-with-multiple-view-models)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind this way

```
ko.applyBindings(new ModelViewObject(), document.getElementById("pageOne"));
ko.applyBindings(new ModelViewObject(), document.getElementById("pageTwo"));
```

Comment: But this is not the same object, is that ok?

Comment: I want to add single object to multiple pages,

Comment: Is it MVC single page application or ASPX application ?

Comment: Single page application with Jquery mobile

Comment: So this is right approach to bind multiple pages with same viewmodel

Comment: @ExCode take a look at [this](http://raheelshan.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/with-binding-magic-writing-single-page-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-knockoutjs/) for SPA